# JSON or Jquery error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to make an ajax call using the below jQuery.

But I can see in Chrome, i'm getting uncaught typeerror cannot read property 'error' of null. So this stops the preloader from going away. Any idea why it's doing this?

```
function appendTeam(){

$.ajax({

       url : _path + "/core/ajax.php",
       type : 'POST',
       data : { f: 'getTeam'},
       dataType : 'json',
       success :  function(data) {

        if(data.error){

            errorMessage('Error: ' + data.error, data.error, data.error);
            return false;

        }else{
            var count = 0;
            $.each(data.team, function(i, c){
                // check
                if(!$('#'+c)) return true;
                var element = $('#'+c);
                $('input[name="s'+i+'"]').val(element.attr('id'));
                $('.slot.'+(i+1)+'.ui-droppable').append(element);
                element.data('prevParent', $('.slot.'+(i+1)+'.ui-droppable'));
                count ++;

            });

            appendStatus(count);
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#preloader').fadeOut('fast',function(){
                    $('#preloader').remove();
                    popUp('match');
                });
            }, 2000);


        }

    }
});
}
```

Comment: Can you add an example of the JSON that Ajax.php is rendering?

Comment: Also the success callbacks don't need/use return statements

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a mistake in your `if` operator:

`if(data.error)...`

You should check it like `if(data && data.error)...` so if the server returned you `null` instead of JSON object you won't try to access object's property `error`.

Also maybe you need to handle this case separately:

```
if(!data) {
    // handle empty response
} else if(data.error) {
    // handle error
} else {
    // process results
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Test if `data` is not `null` before trying acces his `error` property

Answer (score 0):

Probably the `data` object does not contains the property `error` or it is null;

so instead of this

`if(data.error) {`

you can check for it in a different way :

`if(data && data.hasOwnProperty('error')) {`

which is more fail-safe.

Answer (score 0):

i think response is null try to see response in using firebug
[image]